# A good way to manage/maintain privacy and terms pages?

Tags: php, html, css, database, design-patterns

I have word documents of privacy and terms and converted them into php includes that are basically this structure:

```
<div>
   <h1>title</h1>
   <p>text</p>

   <h3>section 1</h3>
   <p>text</p>
</div>
```

I was wanted to get a good design/pattern down to keep maintenance low on these pages. Should I database the html? 
I entered line breaks in the html for the text - should I have kept them as one line and used word wrap in my IDE?

Any other suggestions are welcome. It seems like a very manual process right now and each are 8 pages long. I just want to set a good precedence. Also, I am using Git, if that would influence any decisions.

Comment: As it will rarely change, I don't think using database is a good idea, unless you want to change it frequently. And just a thought of mine, I won't want to read a very long privacy and terms.

Comment: Well that legal speak could be required for their business. Have you seen apple's?